# Problema de lentidão em consulta de PROCEDURE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Existe em meu sistema, uma rotina de envio de e-mail. Onde um ***bat*** do windows executa um arquivo php que faz o envio do mesmo.

O problema está em uma **stored procedure**, que executada direto pelo banco, trás o resultado de forma bem rápida (questão de **0,070 sec**), mas quando executo pelo sistema, ela demora a retornar o resultado e cai em um **FATAL ERROR de tempo Excedido**.

Código:

```
try {
    $connSisDoc = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx.xxx.xx;dbname=xxxx', 'xx', 'xxx');
    $connSisDoc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR SISDOC: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

//verifico os emails pendentes
$sql = "SELECT * FROM documentos_email WHERE doem_enviado = 'N'";
$stmt = $connSisDoc->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$docEmail = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($docEmail as $doem) {
    //pega email dos usuários
    $sql = "SELECT usua_id, usua_nome, usua_email FROM dbacesso.usuario WHERE usua_id = ".$doem->doem_destinatario;
    $stmt = $connSisDoc->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $user = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    //Seta o corpo da mensagem (**o corpo vem de uma função a parte**)
    echo  bodyMail($doem->doem_destinatario, $connSisDoc, $user[0]->usua_nome, $doem->doem_admin, $doem->doem_empr_id);
}

function bodyMail($destinario, $connSisDoc, $nomeDestinatario, $admin, $empresa){
    //Consulto documentos do usuário passado no parametro da função
    $documentos = "SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE xxxx";

    if($admin == 'N')
        $documentos.=" AND doem_destinatario = ". $destinario;

    $stmt = $connSisDoc->prepare($documentos);
    $stmt->execute();
    $docs = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $stmt->closeCursor();

    foreach ($docs as $doc) {
        //Aqui que está acontecendo a lentidão no retorno da consulta
        $sp = "CALL `sp_DocumentosOrgao_Selecionar`('".$doc->doco_id."')";
        $stmt2 = $connSisDoc->prepare($sp);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $orgaos = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $stmt2->closeCursor();
    }

}
```

> Coloquei praticamente todas as consultas que faço em meu código, mas onde ocorre a lentidão, é somente na procedure `CALL sp_DocumentosOrgao_Selecionar($param)`

Comment: E como é essa procedure? Outra procedure executa lentamente também? Quantos documentos ele executa antes de falhar por tempo excedido?

Comment: A procedure é bem complexa, mas se eu executo pelo banco, ele retorna bem rápido, na primeira volta do loop ele já demora, e já ocasiona o FATAL ERROR

Comment: No SQL Server, usando JDBC, às vezes ele perde algumas otimizações que ocorrem ao rodar no SQL Server Management Studio. No caso, já aconteceu de a mesma procedure sendo executada via JDBC dar erro de conversão de dados, mas executando via SQL Server Management Studio funcionar bem. Às vezes algumas interações não ocorrem do modo como esperamos

Comment: e como resolver isso?

Comment: Já tentou outra procedure? Uma de repente que só dê um print "hello, doc"?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, acabei de fazer o teste. criei uma outra procedure com a seguinte sql:  **SELECT 1 as orga_nome**, e funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Você vai precisar postar o procedure para tentarmos descobrir! Não me parece um erro nesse código! É necessário percorrer o caminho lógico para achar o gargalo!